# Change WooCommerce add_to_cart Button Text?

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I am trying to change the add_to_cart button text for all products based on category. For category 'course' with ID 330, I would like the button to read 'Register'.

For all other products, I would like it to read 'Buy Now'.

Here is what I have thus far in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_cat_add_to_cart_text' );
function custom_cat_add_to_cart_text( $default ) {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if ( array_key_exists( 330, $terms ) ) {
            return __( 'Register', 'course' );
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

This is failing to change the button text.

Comment: Try `add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_cat_add_to_cart_text',10,2 );`

Comment: Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because:

```
get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' )
```

yields an array of objects, to test against those objects you have to run a loop and pull a $term_id property out of each object.

Wordpress to the rescue! Wordpress has a helper method for that...

```
has_term(330,'product_cat', $post);
```

Use the [has_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) method to satisfy your conditional.

Comment: Worked like a charm. For others, this is what I have:

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_cat_add_to_cart_text' );
function custom_cat_add_to_cart_text( $default ) {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if ( has_term(330, 'product_cat' , $post) ) {
            return __( 'Register', 'course' );
    } elseif ( has_term(390, 'product_cat' , $post) ) {
            return __( 'Register', 'event' );
    } else {
        return __( 'Buy Now' );
    }
}
`